# is there any function in jsonpath

Tags: function, jsonpath

I'm using the jsonpath in task.json for a custom task in a azure devops extension.

to simplify the problem,
I have a json returned by an azure devops api

```
{"count":1,"value":[
{"variables":{"version":{"value":"2.5.6"},
              "deploymentUser":{"value":"test"},
              "password":{"value":null,"isSecret":true}},
"id":48,
"type":"Vsts",
"name":"myVariableGroup",
"modifiedOn":"2019-08-27T19:52:43.6466667Z",
"isShared":false,
"variableGroupProjectReferences":null}
]
}
```

I need a jsonpath to return the name of variables

```
[version,deploymentUser,password]
```

I read the syntax here https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html
There is no option to select the property names.
I remember somewhere i read some functions could be appear in the jsonpath
something like .keyvalue()

```
$.value[?(@.type=='Vsts')].variables[*].keyvalue().name
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only some implementations support it. It's not part of the original [JSONPath spec](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

[Jayway JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#jayway-jsonpath) - Java

```
$.value[?(@.type=='Vsts')].variables.keys()
```

Test Site: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

---

[JSONPath Plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) - Javascript

```
$.value[?(@.type=='Vsts')].variables.*~
```

Test site: https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: thanks Akshay. 
your answer was very helpful but
unfortunately it seems the jsonpath implementation in requestbody.DataSourceDetails.resultSelector in the following azure devops rest api doesn't support any of your suggestions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpointproxy/execute-service-endpoint-request?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#resulttransformationdetails